# Ubuntu 13.10 is installed on vm ware workstation under virtual machine

Tags: system-installation

i have installed Ubuntu 13.10 on vmware workstation 8 under add virtual machine. i have navigated to me asking to enter full name, user id, pwd and after it has showed all the process of installation and at the end it was showing cmd prompt screen where it is asking "Ubuntu Login". i have waited for 1hour but nothing happened and i am able to see same cmd prompt screen only.

Comment: Hi Savvy,

I have give 1GB RAM. i have installed VM Ware Workstation version 8.0.0.
Through VM ware workstation i tried to add virtual machine to install Ubuntu version 13.10 which i have downloaded from Ubuntu site itself.

please do let me know what i need to do so that Virtual machine i.e. Ubuntu 13.10 will get installed properly in my VM ware workstation 8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please click on [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/383288/edit) (right below your question) to add information to your question instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 0):

Vijaya Chand K:

I believe you just need to login with the name and password that you typed in before.  As I have done with my VM-WARE install.  The first time it asks you for a name and password it is setting up the system user account during the install phase.  The second time is when you are actually logging into operating system after it booted up.

My version of VM-WARE asked me if I wanted to download the additional VMware Tools for ubuntu and I chose "yes".  I would also recommend using any assistance VM-WARE will give you until you are familiar with the installation and configuration process.

After I typed the user name and password again (must be exact), the point at which I believe you were stuck on, I was able to get to the command line interface and use linux commands like:  "ls" and "cd /".  A graphical user interface may or may not be installed.  If you do not see a GUI you can install one buy googling "how to install ubuntu gui"

"Just login in."

-lm